# Autosave Untitled notebooks in $TemporaryDirectory

Tags: autosave

Recently I learned the hard way that there exists autosave functionality for notebooks. When a notebook is not saved yet, though, this feature doesn't work.

**Question:** Is there a way to tell Mathematica to autosave these 'Untitled' notebooks in the $TemporaryDirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must get  the notebooks that need saving:

```
nbs=Select[Notebooks[], (StringMatchQ[
    "WindowTitle" /. NotebookInformation[#], "Untitled*"]) &]
```

Further, we need the name of the notebook:

```
"WindowTitle" /.NotebookInformation[...];
```

Then we need to remember the current notebook:

```
cnb = SelectedNotebook[];
```

With these commands we can save all "Untitled" notebook to the $TemporaryDirectory:

```
cnb = SelectedNotebook[];
nbs = Select[
   Notebooks[], (StringMatchQ["WindowTitle" /. NotebookInformation[#],
       "Untitled*"]) &];
NotebookSave[#, 
    FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "WindowTitle"} /. 
      NotebookInformation[#]]] & /@ nbs;
SetSelectedNotebook[cnb];
```

To execute the above commands say every minute, we put them inside a `Dynamic` with an update interval of 60 sec:

```
Dynamic[
    cnb = SelectedNotebook[];
    nbs = Select[
       Notebooks[], (StringMatchQ["WindowTitle" /. NotebookInformation[#],
           "Untitled*"]) &];
    NotebookSave[#, 
        FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "WindowTitle"} /. 
          NotebookInformation[#]]] & /@ nbs;
    SetSelectedNotebook[cnb];
, UpdateInterval -> 60]
```

Comment: So basically if I add the code to Kernel/init.m I should have default autosave for Untitled notebooks. Is there any chance that problems may arise with computations that run for more than 60s? (not an expert on dynamic...)

Comment: The notebook will be saved as is at 60 seconds, eventually without the result of an ongoing evaluation. But you may easily increase the time interval.