# Change the default name of a new notebook from Untitled-*?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, default

I'd like to change the default name of a new notebook to, say, StringJoin[{RandomWord[],".nb"}].

There is a hint how one might do this in $InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources which contains:

@@resource untitledStringNum
Untitled-

@@resource untitledStringNoNum
Untitled

But, I don't know how the @@resource framework works.  I suppose that I cook up something in init.m along these lines the solution described in [Autosave Untitled notebooks in $TemporaryDirectory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266610/autosave-untitled-notebooks-in-temporarydirectory)

This may be a *very silly* idea--is it?

The reason I'd like to do this is I often end up with ten or so Untitled-?.nb at a time because I open them for scratch work.  I'm wondering if I gave them less similar names, it might help me remember where particular code snippets are located.

Comment: I would very much like to have this, if it's simple and transparent. I would like to have my files starting with the current date `2022-09-30-14PM-NewNotebook.nb`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building upon [Create new notebook at fixed size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100432/5478)

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 NotebookEventActions :> {
  {"MenuCommand", "New"} :> 
    CreateNotebook["Default", WindowTitle -> RandomWord[] <> ".nb"]
 }
]
```

This action is run like a `Method -> "Preemptive"` button so you don't want to make a heavy calculation there. `RandomWord[]` is fast... after data is loaded initially so it is reasonable to worry about that first call.
We can do this like that:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 NotebookEventActions :> {{"MenuCommand", "New"} :> (
     RunScheduledTask[
        SetOptions[#, WindowTitle -> RandomWord[] <> ".nb"], {0}
     ] & @ CreateNotebook["Default"]
     )}
]
```

So a notebook is created immediately and right after a task is scheduled. That's it for the event and the link is released. Then the task starts in the kernel and sets the title once it is ready.

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. Nice solution.

Comment: @rhermans, I think you can insert your date-name into Kuba's solution.

Comment: Do you know where I can find some documentation on NotebookEventActions?  Your solution is great, but if I use the SaveAs menus command, the window title doesn't change while the notebook name is changed.   I can change the window title explicitly, but I'd like to teach myself how to implement a `NotebookEventActions :> {{"MenuCommand", "Save As"} ` along the lines of what you did above.

Comment: @CraigCarter I guess the best source to learn from is here: [q=NotebookEventActions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=NotebookEventActions). I am not 100% what do you want to do during SaveAs but you need to use `EvaluationNotebook[]` to specify partent notebook as opposed to the code above. Additionaly take a look at `EvaluationOrder` options described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162314/5478) because it matters for Close/Save events. Let me know in case I missed your point. Best.

Comment: I'll have to look at this tomorrow, but to clarify: I just want to change the window title to whatever filename I specify as "Save As". 

Currently, if I save the a notebook with  WindowTitle -> RandomWord[] <> ".nb", with a filename (e.g, "working_code.nb"), the WindowTitle remains the same as expected.  Nott a huge problem because I can change the WindowTitle option explicitly (in fact, there is a convenient pull-down menu in the Option Inspector.)

This is a tangent from the original posting where the intent was to have a gimmick to name scratch notebooks and not to save them.

Comment: Mostly, I just wanted to learn how to extend the `NotebookEventActions :> {{"MenuCommand", "Save As"} ` example that you constructed--and the documentation is sparse.